# Does Photoshop 2018 allow recordings of "Save for Web" action for batch processing?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, batch-processing, save, actions

I have made several attempts at recording the Export > Save for Web (Legacy) script where I select the File Size Optimization to reduce the file size of several .jpg images.

However, when I run the script the file size is unaffected.

Thank you!

Comment: They used to have that as a built-in function, but took it out. Now they want you to use Lightroom CC. Which I tried and just had to stop! It is a pity. Why the script recording does not work is likely tied to the above, but I am not sure.

Comment: Can i batch process in Lightroom? I just need to reduce the file size of 150 images.

Comment: Yes, Photoshop CC 2018 does record Save for Web (Legacy) in actions. Are you trying to recompress images that are already jpeg?  That's not really a good idea.  Ideally, Save for Web is for exporting an uncompressed source image.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue so far, I have used Image Processor (File > Scripts > Image Processor) and reduced the image quality. I used the File Size Optimization option from Save for Web to give me an idea of the quality I should reduce by based on my desired file size. The only issue is that every image is slightly different resulting in a variation of file sizes. Since my images were very similar this was not a huge issue, for very diverse images this work-around would not be ideal.